# How to quit the rspec test suite in the terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm currently working on an app that has a large test suite (ten minutes to run). What is the command to force quit the test?

Comment: DId you try ctr+c or ctr+d?

Comment: I did and it worked. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `ctr+c`

> Control-C is a common computer command. It is generated by pressing the C key while holding down the Ctrl key on most computer keyboards. In graphical user interface environments that use the control key to control the active program, control-C is often used to copy highlighted text to the clipboard.

you can also try `ctrl+d`

> Control-D is a shortcut for "Fill Down"

Comment: Thanks for the Help!